# Check if Boost Interprocess managed_shared_memory already exists?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-interprocess

Is there a way (other than a try-catch) to determine whether a `boost::interprocess:managed_shared_memory` region with a particular name already exists?

I know if I allocate an Interprocess vector within the managed_shared_memory region I can check it's existence using managed_shared_memory::find(), but there doesn't appear to be a way to check whether the managed_shared_memory region itself exists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a better way to check for the existence of a boost shared memory segment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25574401/is-there-a-better-way-to-check-for-the-existence-of-a-boost-shared-memory-segmen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the constructor with `boost::interprocess::open_or_create`.

If you want to  know which of the two happened, you can use `boost::interprocess::open_only` or `boost::interprocess::create_only` but you'll have add "external" synchronization on top: [c++ Synchronize shared memory when reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49808659/c-synchronize-shared-memory-when-reading/49815972#49815972)

Comment: Isn't that effectively suggesting using a try-catch? Try creating using create_only, if it fails you know the memory didn't exist?

Comment: No, that's pointing out the different approaches you can use. You do not have to. In fact, you haven't told us why you think you have to.

Comment: Oh, by the way, if you know the platform details, you can, of course, use that knowledge (look for the file nodes under `/dev/shm/` e.g.). But I would suggest "abusing" exception handling over abusing implementation details that make the code non-portable