# Is boost interprocess managed_shared_memory thread safe?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-interprocess

I have two processes P1 and P2 implementing IPC using `boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory`. Both use the following snippet of code:

```cpp
namespace ipc = boost::interprocess;

// Open a shared memory segment with given name and size
ipc::managed_shared_memory segment_(ipc::open_or_create, "shared_memory_segment", 1024);

// Immediately proceed to create objects using find_or_construct
auto heartbeat_p1 = segment_.find_or_construct<std::atomic<int64_t>>("heartbeat_p1")(0);
// .. other shared objects

// And then proceed to use them
```

I think the usage of `open_or_create` isn't thread-safe here, and does it require an external synchronization?

What might go wrong is either of two cases -

1. *This is not going to introduce any race conditions. Calls inside open() are going to constitute of OS system calls, which are taken care of by OS (similar to open syscall). Leaving this point for completeness of the question.*

Both P1 and P2 enter the code for the constructor of `segment_`. And since `open_or_create` is itself a logic that can be represented as:

```cpp
try {
    create();
}
catch {
  if (already_exists_error){
     try {
       open();
      }
  }
  else {
     throw();
  }
}
```

We might have a race condition if both try to `create()` at the same time?

2. If P1 is inside open() but hasn't completed making the data structures inside the shared memory that is still needed for the proper functioning of the managed memory segment. And, meanwhile, now P2 is fired, it directly proceeds to open, and attaches to it, a segment which hasn't been completely created. Won't P2 be left with an undefined state for the shared memory object?

I have seen my setup behaving weirdly in which the objects in boost managed shared memory aren't really "shared" across process. And there is no exception being thrown either.

Reference for try-catch block: [Is there a better way to check for the existence of a boost shared memory segment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25574401/is-there-a-better-way-to-check-for-the-existence-of-a-boost-shared-memory-segmen/).

[c++ Synchronize shared memory when reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49808659/c-synchronize-shared-memory-when-reading/49815972) also mentions to use external synchronization for reading from a process.

Is my understanding correct that we need external synchronization in using `open_or_create` from two different processes? And if yes, how do I properly synchronize so that both can use `open_or_create`?

Comment: I don't know but what does the documentation say? If it does not have an explicit statement that it is threadsafe... then it is not

Comment: @PepijnKramer the document simply says, what the try-catch block is inteded to do. It doesn't say anything about thread safety for creation of the object, but it does say find_or_construct being atomic.

Comment: Now you made me look : section ["synchronization guarantees"](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html#interprocess.managed_memory_segments.managed_memory_segment_features.synchronization). Seems to give guarantees between two processes, not between threads. It uses [interprocess_mutex](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/interprocess_r_idp34570304.html) not some local mutex. But all in all I think I would need to read more, and I don't have the time for that.

Comment: @PepijnKramer It mentions about synchronizaiton gurantees _after_ the segment has been constructed.. for the segment itself, it is this section mentions what I have stated above:  https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html#interprocess.managed_memory_segments.managed_mapped_files.constructing_managed_mapped_files

Comment: That's what I mean I don't have the focus to look into it in detail. But maybe you can use an interprocess mutex of your own to synchronize the creation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I went through the boost source code, and found following observations:

**TL;DR** : *NOPE*, we do not need any external synchronization here, since boost source ensures that all calls are synchronized either by OS system calls, or by the atomic reads and compare-and-swap writes into the starting address of the shared memory segment used as an enum.

**Longer version**:
If we sail our way through boost managed_memory_segment source code, all the important bits can be found in this object's constructor:

*managed_open_or_create_impl.hpp*:

```cpp
// boost::ipc::managed_shared_memory dervies from:
// Skipping non-important arguments and templates for this answer

class managed_open_or_create_impl
{
 managed_open_or_create_impl()
 {
  priv_open_or_create();
 }

 void priv_open_or_create() 
 {
  bool created = false;
  // more code ...
  else { //DoOpenOrCreate
         created = this->do_create_else_open(dev, id, size, perm);
      }

  // on basis of created variable
  if(created){
         this->do_map_after_create(dev, m_mapped_region, size, addr, construct_func);
      }
      else{
         this->do_map_after_open(dev, m_mapped_region, addr, construct_func, ronly, cow);
      }
 }

}
```

So we have 3 functions of interest here:
*do_create_else_open(), do_map_after_create(), do_map_after_open()*.

Let's go through them one-by-one:

```cpp
template <class DeviceId>
   static bool do_create_else_open(DeviceAbstraction &dev, const DeviceId & id, std::size_t size, const permissions &perm)
   {
      spin_wait swait;
      unsigned tries = 0;
      while(1){
         BOOST_TRY{
            create_device<FileBased>(dev, id, size, perm, file_like_t());
            return true;
         }
         BOOST_CATCH(interprocess_exception &ex){
            #ifndef BOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS
            if(ex.get_error_code() != already_exists_error){
               BOOST_RETHROW
            }
            else if (++tries == MaxCreateOrOpenTries) {
               //File existing when trying to create, but non-existing when
               //trying to open, and tried MaxCreateOrOpenTries times. Something fishy
               //is happening here and we can't solve it
               throw interprocess_exception(error_info(corrupted_error));
            }
            else{
               BOOST_TRY{
                  DeviceAbstraction tmp(open_only, id, read_write);
                  dev.swap(tmp);
                  return false;
               }
               BOOST_CATCH(interprocess_exception &e){
                  if(e.get_error_code() != not_found_error){
                     BOOST_RETHROW
                  }
               }
               BOOST_CATCH(...){
                  BOOST_RETHROW
               } BOOST_CATCH_END
            }
            #endif   //#ifndef BOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS
         }
         BOOST_CATCH(...){
            BOOST_RETHROW
         } BOOST_CATCH_END
         swait.yield();
      }
      return false;
   }
```

1. Okay, so this is simple, it wraps the try-catch block inside the create_device calls. The create_device expands to shm_open() and is bound to be atomic due to it being an OS system call, similar to file open. So, one process is bound to throw and enters the catch block, where it simply attaches the the OS shared memory already created.
2. And the one who creates it calls do_map_after_create(). The one who attaches calls do_map_after_open().

*do_map_after_create()*:

```cpp
void do_map_after_create()
{
      BOOST_TRY{
         //If this throws, we are lost
         truncate_device<FileBased>(dev, static_cast<offset_t>(size), file_like_t());

         //If the following throws, we will truncate the file to 1
         mapped_region region(dev, read_write, 0, 0, addr);
         boost::uint32_t *patomic_word = 0;  //avoid gcc warning
         patomic_word = static_cast<boost::uint32_t*>(region.get_address());
         boost::uint32_t previous = atomic_cas32(patomic_word, InitializingSegment, UninitializedSegment);

         if(previous == UninitializedSegment){
            BOOST_TRY{
               construct_func( static_cast<char*>(region.get_address()) + ManagedOpenOrCreateUserOffset
                              , size - ManagedOpenOrCreateUserOffset, true);
               //All ok, just move resources to the external mapped region
               final_region.swap(region);
            }
            BOOST_CATCH(...){
               atomic_write32(patomic_word, CorruptedSegment);
               BOOST_RETHROW
            } BOOST_CATCH_END
            atomic_write32(patomic_word, InitializedSegment);
         }
         else{
            atomic_write32(patomic_word, CorruptedSegment);
            throw interprocess_exception(error_info(corrupted_error));
         }
      }
      BOOST_CATCH(...){
         BOOST_TRY{
            truncate_device<FileBased>(dev, 1u, file_like_t());
         }
         BOOST_CATCH(...){
         }
         BOOST_CATCH_END
         BOOST_RETHROW
      }
      BOOST_CATCH_END
   }
```

1. Firstly, it truncates the shared memory to the specified size. Takes the initial memory pointer to the shared memory segment, and performs an atomic compare-and-swap to write an enum of value InitializingSegment. Note, just after truncating the value is set to 0 by default by OS, so the enum value is UninitializedSegment.
2. After writing the enum successfully to InitializingSegment, it constructs objects needed for the functioning of the segment. Completing that, it updates the enum to InitializedSegment atomicaly.

Now, *do_map_after_open()*, broken into 2 parts:
Part-1:

```cpp
void do_map_after_open()
{
      const usduration TimeoutSec(usduration_seconds(MaxInitializeTimeSec));

      if(FileBased){
         offset_t filesize = 0;
         spin_wait swait;

         //If a file device was used, the creator might be truncating the device, so wait
         //until the file size is enough to map the initial word
         ustime ustime_start = microsec_clock<ustime>::universal_time();

         while(1){
            if(!get_file_size(file_handle_from_mapping_handle(dev.get_mapping_handle()), filesize)){
               error_info err = system_error_code();
               throw interprocess_exception(err);
            }
            if (filesize != 0)
               break;
            else {
               //More than MaxZeroTruncateTimeSec seconds waiting to the creator
               //to minimally increase the size of the file: something bad has happened
               const usduration elapsed(microsec_clock<ustime>::universal_time() - ustime_start);
               if (elapsed > TimeoutSec){
                  throw interprocess_exception(error_info(corrupted_error));
               }
               swait.yield();
            }
         }
         //The creator detected an error creating the file and signalled it with size 1
         if(filesize == 1){
            throw interprocess_exception(error_info(corrupted_error));
         }
      }
      // .. more code later
}
```

In part-1:

1. It checks if the file opened in shm_open has been truncated yet or not by matching the size of the file. If truncated it proceeds further. It checks it only for a number of retries not exceeding TimeoutSec = MaxInitializeTimeSec (300u).

Part-2

```cpp
{
      // continued;
      mapped_region  region(dev, ronly ? read_only : (cow ? copy_on_write : read_write), 0, 0, addr);

      boost::uint32_t *patomic_word = static_cast<boost::uint32_t*>(region.get_address());
      boost::uint32_t value = atomic_read32(patomic_word);

      if (value != InitializedSegment){
         ustime ustime_start = microsec_clock<ustime>::universal_time();
         spin_wait swait;
         while ((value = atomic_read32(patomic_word)) != InitializedSegment){
            if(value == CorruptedSegment){
               throw interprocess_exception(error_info(corrupted_error));
            }
            //More than MaxZeroTruncateTimeSec seconds waiting to the creator
            //to minimally increase the size of the file: something bad has happened
            const usduration elapsed(microsec_clock<ustime>::universal_time() - ustime_start);
            if (elapsed > TimeoutSec){
               throw interprocess_exception(error_info(corrupted_error));
            }
            swait.yield();
         }
         //The size of the file might have grown while Uninitialized -> Initializing, so remap
         {
            mapped_region null_map;
            region.swap(null_map);
         }
         mapped_region  final_size_map(dev, ronly ? read_only : (cow ? copy_on_write : read_write), 0, 0, addr);
         final_size_map.swap(region);
      }
      construct_func( static_cast<char*>(region.get_address()) + ManagedOpenOrCreateUserOffset
                     , region.get_size() - ManagedOpenOrCreateUserOffset
                     , false);
      //All ok, just move resources to the external mapped region
      final_region.swap(region);
}
```

2. Now, this part reads the starting address of the shared memory atomically and waits until the enum value is set to InitializedSegment. It also throws if it can't open it after TimeoutSec.
3. Completing the wait successfully, it makes it own object of mapped_region object.

Thus, all calls are synchronized either by OS system calls, or by the atomic reads and compare-and-swap enum writes into the starting address of the shared memory segment.

**Edit:** I finally found the issue for which Processes were not able to attach themselves to the same shared memory segment. It was due to systemd deleting the shared memory resources for a user account on logouts. Link: https://superuser.com/a/1179962/1818191

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you should have external synchronization if two processes might create the shared segment at the same time.

Note, a very usual situation is where one process is the creating side, and all other(s) are accessing the existent memory realm. You often don't need to synchronize creation because it happens-before other access for external reasons.

If your situation is similar, but you still want to be robust under unexpected startup sequences, add some error-handling and perhaps a retry loop at the "client".

Comment: I dont have a server-client relationship. My process can come and go as they want to.. I am trying to design it this way, and both should be allowed to create the segment. That's why I am trying to use open_or_create, whichever fires first creates it. What is the best way to synchronize this externally? Can you add that in the answer, and I can accept it then. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You linked to [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49808659/c-synchronize-shared-memory-when-reading/49815972) where I showed you how you might. In this answer I already describe how I would do it ([retry loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76611543/is-boost-interprocess-managed-shared-memory-thread-safe/76612344?noredirect=1#comment135077190_76612344:~:text=add%20some%20error%2Dhandling%20and%20perhaps%20a%20retry%20loop%20at%20the%20%22client%22)) instead.

Comment: See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67966958/boost-find-in-shared-memory-method-get-stuck-in-c-multi-process-project/67970027#67970027

Comment: Boost authors provide examples in the documentation without any kind of user-level synchronisation. Do you think they omit a vital part of the example so their documentation is useless? If so, you should not use their product at all because you don't tust them.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit Who are you talking to? What are you talking about? Is there something you want to correct about my answer?

Comment: "Is there something you want to correct about my answer?" Yes there is. "Indeed, you should have external synchronization" This point is wrong, it is not required because the documentation does not say it is required and provides examples of presumably correct code without such synchronization.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit That logic fails. There are places in the documentation where the need for synchronization is reiterated. Are you also outraged that cppreference.com shows examples of vector
element indexing with `operator[]` instead of `.at()`? Or when people answer on SO explaining that a bounds-check is missing? You would be equally mind blown
but they show examples of using console output without thread synchronization.

Comment: The point is, you always have to add these if you need them. And there are many
ways to make it work correctly without additional synchronization (my answer explains this). Still, there are some reasons and many
scenarious in which I will not "just use" managed_XYZ directly. The reasons among others: problems with non-robust locking, inability to grow/version/detect incompatible layouts (leading to UB). I have many answers on this site with workarounds and suggestions on how to overcome these limitations. Hope that helps.

Comment: @sehe I don't think we need external synchronization here. Please see my answer. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Boost does all of the synchronisation needed internally, so you don't have to. See their code examples in the documentation. There is no user-level synchronisation mentioned or shown anywhere.

If you don't trust the documentation, then you should not be using the product.